# PHP Connection with neo4j "cURL error 7"

Tags: php, laravel, curl, neo4j

I followed steps in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452932/use-of-neoxygen-neoclient-as-a-serviceproviderfacade-into-laravel-5-1/32442595?noredirect=1#comment52752193_32442595) but this error appeared to me, Can you help please?

> HttpException in HttpRequestEventSubscriber.php line 74: Error on
>   Connection "default" with message "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to
>   localhost port 7474: Connection refused (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

this is my .env code

```
`APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=ChTIcRHTSR35M6rP0jwmOmhMNLuFpMVe

NEO4J_HOST=localhost
NEO4J_PORT=7474
NEO4J_USER=neo4j
NEO4J_PASSWORD=admin
NEO4J_TIMEOUT=300

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
`
```

this is NeoClientServiceProvider code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

class NeoClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('neoclient', function ($app) {
            return ClientBuilder::create()
                ->addConnection('default', 'http', env('NEO4J_HOST'), intval(env('NEO4J_PORT')), true, env('NEO4J_USER'), env('NEO4J_PASSWORD'))
                ->setDefaultTimeout( intval(env('NEO4J_TIMEOUT')) )
                ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
                ->build();
        });
    }
}
```

this is provider

```
 App\Providers\NeoClientServiceProvider::class,
```

aliases

```
'NeoClient' => App\NeoClient::class
```

this is NeoClient class code

```
 <?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class NeoClient extends Facade
{

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'neoclient'; }
}
```

my test controller

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\NeoClient;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class test extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $data = NeoClient::sendCypherQuery('CREATE (user:User {name:"Kenneth"}) RETURN user');

    }

}
```

when I made dump for this in function addConnection which is in ClientBuilder class

```
 public function addConnection($alias, $scheme, $host, $port, $authMode = false, $authUser = null, $authPassword = null)
    {
        $this->configuration['connections'][$alias] = array(
            'scheme' => $scheme,
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => $authMode,
            'user' => $authUser,
            'password' => $authPassword,
        );
  dd($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

[image: this is the results of dump]

Comment: the error is quite clear: probably nobody is listening on that port

Comment: how?, this port is for neo4j connection http://localhost:7474/ this the link that I am using to open neo4j browser.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are executing. That error can have 42 different reasons.

Comment: ok, I will do it now.

Comment: It seems your unauthorized. Can you test this command in the terminal and check that the response status code is 200 : `curl --user neo4j:admin "http://localhost:7474/db/data/" -v` . If not check that the provided password is good

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen  yes, status code is 200. (`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`)

Comment: strange, all the laravel config seems good. possible there is any whitespace around the user and password in the .env file?

Comment: No , it's as i wrote above.

Comment: is your code hosted somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately it is localhost, using homestead. I added some information in the post.

Comment: Ok. So is homestead vagrant localhost different than the localhost used by the neo4j server : on the host then ?

Comment: as a quick test, try to change `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` in your `.env` file

Comment: yes, it is different.

Comment: I tried it more times ago, and the same problem happened.

Comment: `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7474`

Comment: yes but as you are coming from a VM, did you changed the neo4j setting to allow outside connections : so uncomment the following line in `neo4j-server.properties` : `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: and restart the neo4j server

Comment: when i used wamp server it worked, So what is wrong with homestead?

Comment: it runs in a virtual machine, so homestead is `guest` of your computer which is `host` meaning that it has its own ports, dns, ...

Comment: what is the vagrant host ip ? 192.168.10.10 ?

Comment: seems like you have neo4j installed on your host machine `localhost`, and what you're trying to do is access the host machine from the `guest` (homestead). Maybe this can help: http://superuser.com/a/310745

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Yes, 192.168.10.10 , and i tried to replace localhost with 192.168.10.10 in .env file but the same problem appeared.

Comment: finally found and working, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I installed Homestead to reproduce your environment. As told in the comments this should have been a host issue. I managed to make your connection to neo4j working :

1. ssh to homestead :

`ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222`

2. display the gateway ip of the vagrant box :

`vagrant@homestead:~$ ip route show
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10`

Here the host gateway is *10.0.2.2*

3. Use the gateway as neo4j host :

`$ curl --user neo4j:admin "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/"
  "extensions" : { },
  "node" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/node",
  "node_index" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "indexes" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/schema/index",
  "constraints" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/schema/constraint",
  "transaction" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/transaction",
  "node_labels" : "http://10.0.2.2:7474/db/data/labels",
  "neo4j_version" : "3.0.0-alpha.163"`

Comment: Thank you very very very muuuuuch :)